# After an upgrade, Unity system settings are transparent

Tags: unity, system-settings

I've upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04 and I now have a problem with my settings. If I go on system settings, there is no problem. But if I click on any icons, I get a partially transparent windows:

[image: Sound settings]

I share here the sound setting page in front of a terminal. It's the same problem on each settings page. I've already reboot many times and all updates have been installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to delete this package gnome-settings-daemon using :

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-settings-daemon
```

Comment: Why would this work?

Comment: @Braiam --- I think that the Gnome DE and Unity are mildly incompatible. I seem to remember that somewhere along the path the `gnome-settings-daemon` was forked for Unity --- so maybe some remnant package? (Not sure, because I run Gnome Shell).